# Cannot find module azure function double_edge.js

Tags: javascript, function, azure

I have a trouble when I want to run locally an azure function in vscode or vs enterprise 2017, the error is:

[image]

I tried this and nothing work:

1. Create a mklink to replace special characters in my name to can
   find the path.
2. Change the route of the npm azure tools, so when I execute the
   command: `npm root -g` the path is a custom path that I created to the
   test, but the application still try to find in the error path.

The main error is the special symbols in my user name, the accent mark.

I don't know what I can do, sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 2):

This issue is in the underlying dependencies of the core-tools, namely https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host which is using edgejs. And from [this thread](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/182), you could try to download a zipfile manually from the URL specified here: https://aka.ms/functions-cli or download from the releases page: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-cli/releases, then install this tool in a different folder.

Answer (score 1):

My username also caused me the same problem and I didn't know how to make Visual Studio read the Functions Tools files from another folder.

What solved the problem for me was to move the **cli_x64** and **templates** -folders (in path_to_azFuncTools/releases/1.10.0) to a directory without a problematic username (e.g. C:\Users\Default\AppData\AzureFunctionsTools).

Then, in **path_to_azFuncTools/releases/1.10.0/manifest.json**, I changed the fields  "CliEntrypointPath" and "TemplatesDirectory" to correspond to the new file path and it started working.